SwiftUI @FocusState re-rendering the view when the keyboard first appears
I have "NewEditListView" which lets you create a new "ListItem" (SwiftDate Object) or edit it, my issue is when I show the keyboard (for the first time only) to edit the "ListItem" name it causes re-rendering view, and call "ListItemManager.configureList(for: id, context)" method inside view model for the second time and that made new "ListItem" or pass edited "ListItem" to new Model Context using given "id", how can avoid this issue?
I don't know if that made any effect but I present the view using the sheet.
The view model:
extension NewEditListView {
    
    @Observable
    final class ViewModel {
        
        // MARK: - Properties
        var list: ListItem
               
        // MARK: - Init
        init(id: PersistentIdentifier?, _ container: ModelContainer) {
            let context = ModelContext(container)
            self.list = ListItemManager.configureList(for: id, context)
        }       
    }
}

The view:
struct NewEditListView: View {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    let id: PersistentIdentifier?
    @State private var viewModel: ViewModel
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    init(id: PersistentIdentifier?, container: ModelContainer) {
        self.id = id
        let viewModel = ViewModel(id: id, container)
        _viewModel = State(initialValue: viewModel)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 24) {
                    textField
                }
                .padding(.top, 24)
            }
            .navigationTitle(viewModel.initialListItem.isNew ? "New List" : "Edit List")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
                    isFocused = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Views 
    private var textField: some View {
        TextField("List name", text: $viewModel.list.name)
            .font(.title3)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .submitLabel(.done)
            .padding(.leading, 16)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 48)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .focused($isFocused)
    }
}

presenting the view:
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentingSheet, content: {
            NewEditListView(id: nil, container: context.container)
        })


In SwiftUI the View structs are the view model so you can simply remove that class. It doesn't render anything it just recomputes structs which is negligible. It's the internal diffing of the structs that creates UIKit objects that does something.

You could try .sheet(item: ...) or capture the variable, such as:
.sheet(isPresented: $presentingSheet) { [context.container] in             NewEditListView(id: nil, container: context.container)         }

I used ".sheet(item: ...)" and "[context.container] in" and got the same issue.

To fix this issue we need to:

make the list "@Bindable var list: ListItem" inside "NewEditListView"
The list that we pass it to "NewEditListView" its need to be "@State var list: ListItem"

